# Web-based code editor with iOS support

Tags: web-apps, software-development, ios

Looking for a web-based text editor that works on iOS.

Seems like both Ace and CodeMirror work somewhat, but [don't](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/37) [really](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/60) support mobile.

It doesn't have to be the most complicated thing with all the features in the world.

I'm looking for something that's worth upgrading from a standard textarea. And which works well on modern iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your priority is a web-based text editor that runs from Safari or if you're looking for a web service with a good iOS counterpart.

For the latter, I recommend you take a look at [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com). They recently updated their [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/hr/app/codeanywhere/id436736239?mt=8) and it looks better than ever.

Comment: I appreciate the response. The question is actually aiming at a web based text editor, like Ace or CodeMirror. Suitable for use directly in MobileSafari or in a UIWebView, perhaps through Cordova.